# Facebook Hacker Cup: After the Dance Battle

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

We want to find the shortest path between two points in a special grid. We can travel between adjacent squares in a single move, but we can also travel between cells of the same type (there are 10 types) in a single move no matter the distance between them.

How can we find the the number of steps required to travel between two points for a grid of up to 100x100 in size?

Comment: What is the question?  What is the tag facebook-hacker-up?

Comment: @Stefan Read the output section. Facebook Hacker Cup is a programming competition.

Comment: @Marcog: There is no question here

Comment: @Stefan "Return the number of steps required to reach the exit from the starting point." Does it really have to be stated with a question mark?

Comment: Well, it is a programming competition, yeah, but SO isn't a place to just copy competition problems to.

Comment: @marcog: I think this is more of a "do this for me" question, which i don't think are liked very much on SO. Have you attempted to come up with a solution to this before posting it?

Comment: This is a problem.  A puzzle.  Not a question.

Comment: @Sergei I just did the contest, so yes I did. I'm posting it because it's an interesting question.

Comment: Which would be a good addition: "I just did the problem and thought it's an interesting question. What are your thoughts/ideas on this?"

Comment: I've greatly shortened the wording. Hopefully that makes it better.

Comment: @ypnos Your comment is meaningless. Please give a reason.

Comment: Interesting that StackOverflow is welcoming of mundane questions ("How do I get rounded corners in CSS?" is one of the most popular questions on the website) but not of questions with actual algorithmic content.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Because these "mundane" questions could possibly help hundreds of people as they pertain to actual real-world problems. A puzzle question doesn't have much benefits other than a cool problem to work on when you have free time.

Comment: @Sergei Algorithms are also very real-world. Just because this exact problem doesn't have a known real-world analogy, learning how to solve it does help solve real-world algorithmic problems.

Comment: @Sergei: Fair enough, but what I find remarkable are the people who not only prefer to devote their time to the everyday useful questions rather than "cool problems to work on" (fine), but also actively vote to prevent those of the opposite persuasion from answering these questions if they want… thereby signalling that such questions and people are not welcome here, and that their presence makes this website worse. Does it?

Comment: To close voters and everyone thinking this is not "real world" and what not: IMHO any programming question that is of genuine interest to the SO community is in place here. Are all questions here always about "I have problem X at work, I need this solved ASAP"? I really do not know any programmer worth his salt who does not study/like algorithms and problems that make one think. In any case, this is an infinitely more interesting question that any CSS issue I have ever faced.

Comment: I wish you had asked the question beore. I haven't heard about fb hacker cup, and it is closed now.

Comment: Did anyone notice the sample testcase and the actual testcases were of different format? :( i lost time there... :(

Comment: Making this a Community Wiki would most likely prevent this from being closed.

Comment: @Lieven While I disagree (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888#55997)), if you think so you should flag it for moderator attention. Normal users can no longer do so. I have yet to hear a valid reason for closing this though. The [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) clearly includes "a software algorithm" which is what this is. Just because a question doesn't interest you is not a reason to close it (add [algorithm] as an ignored tag if that is the case). The one "too localised" vote doesn't make sense either as the ideas here can be applied to similar problems.

Comment: @marcog - I had no idea we could no longer make a question CW, thanks for pointing that out. I assumed you were just out for a quick rep boost. It's clearly I was mistaken, my appologies. *I can't seem to revoke the close vote though*

Comment: @Lieven Ironically I've only gained 12 rep from posting this, because I hit they daily rep cap. :) No worries though, it was an honest mistake. The way it's going this is very likely to be closed, but hopefully we'll get enough reopen votes. :-/

Comment: @marcog, for what it's worth, I'll vote to reopen to repair the damage done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make 10 arrays, each one containing the cells of corresponding type. Now run Dijkstra (or BFS), but when you visit a cell of type `i`, add all cells of type `i` to the queue and clear the corresponding array. This way you don't have to visit every edge between cells of the same type and the complexity is O(n^2) instead of O(n^4)

Comment: Why use Dijkstra's when BFS is sufficient?

Comment: @Chris Of course it is, but the main part is to avoid traversing all 10^8 edges.

Comment: your algorithm would run in `O(n^2)` with BFS as well, wouldn't it? So there's no need to use Dijkstra. Looks good though, +1.

Comment: Interesting. I overlooked this, but this sounds like what I was leading to as I mentioned in my comment on @MAK's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this one during the contest by using BFS.

The problem can be modeled as a graph. Each cell is a node and has an edge with each adjacent cell. Instead of building the graph explicitly, we can simply keep the graph implicit by visiting each cell and its neighbours by computing grid coordinates as needed.

Each cell also has an edge to all cells of the same colour. We can add this to our graph by keeping lists of cells of each colour and visiting all cells of the same colour as the current cell.

Something like Dijkstra or A* would work (they are essentially a BFS with a priority queue/heuristic after all), but implementing that for such a simple problem would be serious overkill.

Code follows (in C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map> 

using namespace std;

char grid[101][101];
int cost[101][101];

vector<pair<int,int> > colour[10]; // lists of same coloured cells

//used to compute adjacent cells
int dr[]={ 0, 0, 1,-1};
int dc[]={ 1,-1, 0,0};

int rows,cols; // total rows and coloumns


int bfs(pair<int,int> start){
    memset(cost,-1,sizeof(cost)); // all unvisited nodes have negative cost to mark them
    cost[start.first][start.second]=0; // start node has cost 0

    queue<pair<int,int> > Q;
    Q.push(start);

    while (!Q.empty()){

        pair<int,int> node=Q.front();Q.pop();
        int r=node.first;
        int c=node.second;
        int cst=cost[r][c];
        if (grid[r][c]=='E'){
            return cst;
        }

        // search adjacent cells
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            int nr=r+dr[i];
            int nc=c+dc[i];
            if (nr>=0 && nr<rows && nc>=0 && nc<cols && cost[nr][nc]<0 && grid[nr][nc]!='W'){
                cost[nr][nc]=cst+1;
                Q.push(make_pair(nr,nc));
            }
        }

        // search cells of the same colour
        if (grid[r][c]>='1' && grid[r][c]<='9'){
            vector<pair<int,int> > &trans=colour[grid[r][c]-'0'];
            for(int i=0;i<trans.size();i++){
                pair<int,int> next=trans[i];
                if (cost[next.first][next.second]<0){
                    cost[next.first][next.second]=cst+1;
                    Q.push(next);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    while(N--){
        cerr<<"cases left"<<N<<endl;
        cin>>rows>>cols;
        pair<int,int> start;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) colour[i].clear();

        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
                cin>>grid[i][j];

                if (grid[i][j]=='S'){
                    start=make_pair(i,j);
                }
                else if (grid[i][j]>='1' && grid[i][j]<='9'){
                    colour[grid[i][j]-'0'].push_back(make_pair(i,j));
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<bfs(start)<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this worked I'm going to kick myself, because I implemented it in Python and it seemed to be running to slow on large random input. I was thinking there might be a way to take advantage of the fact that once you hit a "1", then there's only one other sensible "1" to move to.

Comment: @marcog: I generally avoid Python whenever I need large multi-dimensional arrays (`dict`s are even slower). I don't know of any other reason why this would be slow, there are only rows*coloumns nodes and the number of edges is also O(rows*coloumns).

Comment: @MAK But the number of edges can be (row*column)^2 if almost all cells have the same color.

Comment: How fast is this if you have a 100x100 grid of only ones and have to get from (1, 1) to (100, 100)?

Comment: @adamax: Yes, I missed the case where all cells are of the same colour (thus creating a very dense graph). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @|V|lad: On my machine that case takes ~0.6s. We had 6 minutes for all 20 cases.

Comment: Like I said in the other comment, instead of connecting every cell with every other cell, it's probably more effective to have a synthetic vertex for each type with edges connected to all cells of that type and weighing half as much as a normal edge.

Comment: @biziclop: That's correct. But IMHO the code was simpler this way, and it was quite fast enough for the time given.

Comment: @marcog Check my answer for O(n^2) solution. Basically you need to clear the count vector when you reach some of it's vertices.

Comment: I actually overestimated the time taken by the n^4 solution. 100^4 operations are done very fast on a decent machine, so there's no reason an n^4 solution is out of the question. Keep it simple, right? +1.

Comment: @|V|lad: Thanks. I am beginning to suspect that even though the graph is dense, it does not take many iterations of the outer while loop to arrive at the answer (the answer is 3). This can be made worse by increasing the distance between the start and end cells (by having different colours), but that would also make the graph sparser. Having a very dense graph probably offsets the cost to some extent by making the final path shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to solve is model the grid as a graph. Create an edge between 2 neighbors, also create one edge between two nodes of same type. After that, a simple BFS from source to dest can answer the shortest path between the two nodes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

The complexity is O(V+E).  V is the number of nodes, 100x100 and E is the number of edges

People here are mentioning Dijkstra. That solves, but it's desnecessary, since all edges cost one. Dijkstra is a special case of A-star algorithm, so A* is also too much for this problem.

Keep it simple, BFS!

This is a O(R*C) time and O(R*C) space solution:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DanceBattle {
    static final int INF = (int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE * 0.5);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < N ; ++i) {
            int R = in.nextInt();
            int C = in.nextInt();
            int V = R*C;
            int node = 0, start = 0, end = 0;
            int nodeColor[] = new int[V];
            List<Integer>[] colorMap = new List[10];
            for(int color=0;color<10;++color)
                colorMap[color] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            for(int r = 0; r < R; ++r) {
                String row = in.next();
                for(int c = 0; c<row.length(); ++c) {
                    char v = row.charAt(c);
                    if(v == 'S' ) start = node;
                    else if (v == 'E') end = node;
                    else if (v == 'W') nodeColor[node] = -1;
                    else {
                        int color = (int)(v - '0');
                        nodeColor[node] = color;
                        colorMap[color].add(node);
                    }
                    node++;
                }
            }
            int neighborhood4[][] = new int[V][4];
            for(int j =0 ; j< V; ++j) {
                int c = j % C;              
                int r = (j - c)/C;
                int grad = 0;
                if(neighbors(r,c,r,c+1, R, C))
                    neighborhood4[j][grad++] = (r) * C + (c+1);
                if(neighbors(r,c,r,c-1, R, C))
                    neighborhood4[j][grad++] = (r) * C + (c-1);
                if(neighbors(r,c,r+1,c, R, C))
                    neighborhood4[j][grad++] = (r+1) * C + (c);
                if(neighbors(r,c,r-1,c, R, C))
                    neighborhood4[j][grad++] = (r-1) * C + (c);
                if(grad < 4)
                    neighborhood4[j][grad] = -1;
            }

            //bfs
            int qbegin, qend;
            int[] Q = new int[V];
            int[] dist = new int[V];
            for(int j=0; j<V; j++) dist[j] = INF;
            dist[start] = 0;
            qbegin = qend = 0;
            Q[qend++] = start;
            int complexity = 0;
            while(qbegin != qend) {
                int currNode = Q[qbegin++];
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                    int neighbor = neighborhood4[currNode][j];
                    if(neighbor == -1) break;

                    int color = nodeColor[neighbor];
                    if(dist[neighbor] == INF && color != -1 ) {
                        Q[qend++] = neighbor;
                        dist[neighbor] = dist[currNode] + 1;
                    }
                    complexity++;                       
                }
                int color = nodeColor[currNode];
                if (color == 0)
                    continue;
                Iterator<Integer> iter = colorMap[color].iterator();
                while(iter.hasNext()) {
                    int viz = iter.next();
                    if(dist[viz] == INF) {
                        Q[qend++] = viz;
                        dist[viz] = dist[currNode] + 1;
                    }
                    iter.remove();
                    complexity++;                       
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("%d\n",dist[end]);
            //System.out.printf("(compl. %d V=%d constant: %.2f)\n", complexity, V, ((float)complexity) /  V);
        }
    }

    private static boolean neighbors(int ar, int ac, int br, int bc, int R, int C) {
        if(ar < 0 || ac < 0 || br < 0 || bc < 0) return false;
        if(ar >= R || ac >= C || br >= R || bc >= C) return false;
        return (Math.abs(ar - br) <= 1 && Math.abs(ac - bc) ==0) || (Math.abs(ar - br) == 0 && Math.abs(ac - bc) <=1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If someone is wondering about the space complexity: It's not necessary build the graph, but you can use a function that returns all the neighbors of a giving node. Append to the 4 neighbors all nodes with same type. You can precompute it with a multiset: map(t)=>list_of_nodes_of_type_t. So the space complexity is O(V)

Answer (score 1):

You can represent the maze as a graph and solve it using BFS (it works for this case and is simpler than Dijkstra and A*).

In order to fill the edges you can do this:

```
for each row
   for each line
      if char == 'S' mark this point as start
      if char == 'E' mark this point as end
      if char != 'W' then
         create edges between this point and its adjacents (only if they exist and aren't a wall)
         if char >= '1' and char <= '9'
            create edges between this point and everyone with the same color
```

Then apply BFS ([Breadth-first start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)) from `start` to `end` and you're done.

**PS:** In order to save memory, you should represent the graph using adjacency lists, since most of the nodes will have 4 neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a graph of all the squares as vertices with the edges marking possible moves and then let Dijkstra's algorithm work it out.

Comment: This will be too slow as the graph is of size 10,000 with up to 10,000^2 edges.

Comment: @jdv It is 100x100, but that means 10,000 cells and 10,000^2 pairs of cells with a potential edge between them.

Comment: @marcog Define what "too slow" means for you then and what speed you want. All you asked was "How can we find", not "How can we find in (say) O(n*logn) time"

Comment: @biziclop Make it run in constant time! :) Seriously though, a seconds on reasonable hardware. This will take more like a minute.

Comment: Haha, fair enough. :) But you really didn't say it had to be effective. How about creating a synthetic vertex for every type and connecting them with the squares with 1/2 weighted edges? That would only increase the number of vertices by 10 and edges by 10000.

Comment: Notice you have 6 minutes. 100^4 runs in less than a sec.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with [Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Here you define connectivity, and start on the first square. You keep record of the minimal distance found to travel to a certain point. When you reached your endpoint, you find the path by backtracking the route of quickest descent.

In your case, you should define connections between adjacent cells, as well as between the cells of the same color.